# unable to launch usertest.sh

Tags: java

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

When I try to execute

```
sudo ./usertest.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
Java is starting. Press Ctrl-C to exit

Frame buffer device detected: BCM2708

Frame buffer '/dev/fb0' detected: 656x416, depth=16

Failed to open /dev/input/by-id

[ERROR] [LCD] iso=-1:javacall_init_frame_buffer: failed to init keyboards

[CRITICAL] [PROXY] iso=-1:Can't create server

can not connect to device manager

[ERROR] [AMS] iso=0:The MIDlet suite could not be run.
```

Any help please

Comment: What happens if you run it without sudo?

Comment: What is the contents of `usertest.sh`? Is it something to do with [Java me embedded apllication don't start](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=98641)?

Comment: What operating system do you use, what version? If I execute on my Raspbian Buster Light `sudo ./usertest.sh` I get `sudo: ./usertest.sh: command not found`. What is `usertest.sh`?

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle advised to run it as sudo.

see
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RaspberryPi_Setup/RaspberryPi_Setup.html#section4

@Greenonline No. Just the installation. It happens when running the advised user-testing.

Comment: What is usertest.sh? What has Greenonline said? We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a short answer only with a link as context; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or you risk to get down votes.